# Recommend a c++ lib to work with http

Tags: c++, c, http

I need a library to work with http (c++, c). It has to send and receive http requests.
It will be used in a server to answer http requests.
My client - server interaction should use REST model.

Answer (score 5):

Look no further: [CURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) (with its correspondent libcurl) is your best shot in my opinion.

Comment: Is it client side, right? Or i'm wrong

Comment: Yes, it's CLIENT SIDE. For server side, you can just use CGI (or some derivative)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you need two libraries, server-side and client side.

On the server side, I have found [mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) effective for supporting http requests.

On the client side, I have heard many good things about [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).